# How to print variable value multiple time using angularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have data coming from server using `socket.io` For testing purpose i want to generat data multiple times once received so once message received i want to bind it to ng-repeat 5 times. Is it possible to implement using angularJs ?

ctrl.js

```
angular.module('App').controller('DitCtrl',function ($scope,$rootScope,DitFactory,FileSaver,Blob,socket,$uibModal,searchFactory,$timeout) {
    'use strict';
    $scope.event = [];

     socket.on('Consumer',function (data) {
            safelyAdd({
                    id:$scope.event.length,
                    value: data
                });
          for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
              text += $scope.event.value + i + "<br>";
          }

    });
});

function safelyAdd(element){
  if(totalRecieved > Bufferlimit){
     $scope.event =[];//reset array if max size reached..
     totalRecieved = 0;
}
  $scope.event.push(element); //then push new item..
}
```

main.html

```
 <ul style="list-style: none;">
    <li ng-repeat="message in event | limitTo:1000" ng-class="{lastItem: $last}"><span><strong>Log:</strong></span><span>{{message.value}}</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is exactly that you want to display multiple times and why do you want to do that ?

Comment: its a string that i want to display multiple times for testing purpose

Comment: You need to provide more code.. where does `$scope.event`  coming from ? Copy your full controller please

Comment: added my controller $scope.event is array where i am inserting object

Comment: What is `safelyAdd`? Also, your `<br>` will show up as a literal string when you try to display the `text` variable in the view. If you want a line break, add it directly to your HTML.

Comment: I don't see where your `$scope.event` is being filled with objects, so unless the `safelyAdd` function is the one doing so (please paste its code here as well) then your array will remain empty and nothing will be displayed.

Comment: added safely added function to question

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to bind it to ng-repeat 5 times, you can just do `$scope.event.push(element);` 5 times.